# Azure VM shrink Volume C

Tags: azure, azure-storage, shrink

I have created an Azure VM and has a C drive with 127GB. I think it's too much and want to shrink and create another drive "E". Will the new "E" drive remains if I delete the VM in future?

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on whether you choose to delete the OS disk. If you delete the VM without deleting the OS disk, neither drive C nor drive E will be deleted, and you can restore them by recreating an VM and attaching the disk to new VM.

Comment: hi,thanks for the reply. I cannot find an option to keep the OS disk,when deleting the VM. But other attached disks can be kept. pls help me.

Comment: In https://manage.windowsazure.com/ , choose "Virtual Machines" tab, select a VM and click "Delete" -> "Keep the attached disks".

Answer (score -1):

Turn off the VM
Detach the C drive
Then go to managed disk and change size
Attach back to VM 
Start VM 
Once VM boots go to disk manager and confirm new size
Work like a charm for me (usually I have to increase the size)

Comment: The question is about reducing system partition and create additional volume in OS disk, the answer does not address the question.